# How to identify and reject characters from Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols in Unicode, range U+1D400 to U+1D7FF?

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, forms, encoding

I noticed that a user entered text "" in our form when filling out their city. We would like to reject such text in our form. I tried searching for a while, but I couldn't find what type of text this is, and how can I reject it?

Looking further, encoding this text gives an output like: '%F0%9D%99%BC%F0%9D%9A%8A%F0%9D%9A%9B%F0%9D%9A%9C%F0%9D%9A%8B%F0%9D%9A%8E%F0%9D%9A%9B%F0%9D%9A%90', but it does seem like this text is utf-8 encoded.

My knowledge in this field is limited, could someone please guide if there's a way to block such text? or what type of string this is?

Appreciate the help! I will update the question so that it makes more sense once I receive an answer.

Comment: "We would like to reject such text in our form" What text do you want to reject, and what do you want to accept?

Comment: What would you like to reject? non-ASCII characters?

Comment: What would you like to reject? Characters above [Unicode BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane)?

Comment: Hello! Characters like: '' I really don't know what type of characters they are

Comment: These characters are Mathematical monospace letters from the Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols in Unicode, range U+1D400 to U+1D7FF. These are all supplementary characters, outside the basic multilingual plane. [Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D400.pdf) [PDF].

Answer (score 0):

You colud try with a regex that allow only alphanumerical chars:

```js
if (!input.match(/^\w+$/)) {
    return console.log('only alphanumerical chars are allowed')
} else {
    //proceed with script
}
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` start of the string
- `\w` any word character (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _).
- `$` end of the string

Comment: I will try this, but in case I want to allow characters like @ [at rate], ' [apostrophe], then this wouldn't work, right?

Comment: @RishabhBudhiraja yes it would not work, they are not in the regex

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with some event texts coming in.
They contain sometimes a similar UTF8 wording instead of normal ASCII characters..

You can make this visible by displaying the ord number for each:

```
       $splitted = mb_str_split($title);
           foreach ($splitted as $char) {
           echo mb_ord($char) . ' ';
       }
```

This way you could also invalidate the characters of that range: "Please use normal A-Z, ...." etc

Another option would be to make a map of utf8=>ascii characters and auto replace them.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols for a list of all of those in that range.

One example how this could work:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Inflector;

class Utf8Decoder
{
    /**
     * @var array<string>
     */
    protected static array $charMap = [
        119808 => 65, // '' - ''
        119834 => 97, // '' - ''
        120276 => 65, // '' => '',
        120302 => 97, // '' => '',
    ];

    /**
     * @param string $string
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public static function decode(string $string): string
    {
        $charMap = static::charMap();

        $split = mb_str_split($string);
        foreach ($split as $k => $char) {
            $ord = mb_ord($char);

            if (!isset($charMap[$ord])) {
                continue;
            }

            $split[$k] = mb_chr($charMap[$ord]);
        }

        return implode('', $split);
    }

    /**
     * @return array<string, string>
     */
    protected static function charMap(): array
    {
        $charMap = [];

        foreach (static::$charMap as $k => $v) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < 26; $i++) {
                $charMap[$k + $i] = $v + $i;
            }
        }

        return $charMap;
    }
}
```